# How to create the query to mongodb from Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter

I have such collection:

http://prntscr.com/fj87n5

If we open one document we will see

http://prntscr.com/fj882i

As you see driver is an object, I trying to get all documents in which `driver.id = $driver_id`:

```
$driver_id = $this->input->post('driver_id');
    $driverRides = $this->app_model->get_selected_fields(RIDES, array('driver.id' => $driver_id), array('history.end_ride'));


    var_dump($driverRides->num_rows());
    foreach($driverRides->row() as $val){

        var_dump($val);

    }
    die;
```

I see 57 rows (while the collection contains 50 documents). And I didn't see all 50 documents (there is 50 documents with the same driver) in output.

I see this response:

```
int(57)
object(MongoId)#537 (1) {
  ["$id"]=>
  string(24) "58e5ebcc835fe4c902a698e4"
}
array(1) {
  ["end_ride"]=>
  object(MongoDate)#538 (2) {
    ["sec"]=>
    int(1491463147)
    ["usec"]=>
    int(0)
  }
}
```

I think I have see 50 different end_ride outputs. Why is this so?

Answer (score 0):

```
 try{

      $ConnMongo = new MongoClient("mongodb://192.129.1.121/");
      $mdata = $ConnMongo->abc->xyz;

    }
    catch(MongoConnectionException $e){
      exit('START THE MONGO SERVER PLZ ...!!!');
    }

  $data =  $mdata->find(array('driver_id'=>$driver_id));
    echo $datacount = $data->count();
    foreach ( $data as $id)
    {
      echo '<pre>';
      print_r($id);
    }


  }
```

Comment: I use different connection and thid different client

Comment: I dont understand this because the connection already exists in my case and I can not connect as you say

Comment: What do you mean abc->xyz

Comment: this is output $mdata object(MongoDB)#537 (2) {
  ["w"]=>
  int(1)
  ["wtimeout"]=>
  int(10000)
}

Comment: i checked your code(bellow code)...its working fine..can u elaborate what error you are getting!!!

Comment: In general, I would recommend that you add some introductory text to your answers. If only code is provided, readers cannot know what you fixed, or what your strategy was when formulating this work. Thus, there is not much to learn from.